# How to track broken Application indicator icon xubuntu-desktop

Tags: indicator, plugins

I have a broken Application indicator icon in tray. It is a black rectangle with stop sign. No menu available. Is there a way to track the source of that icon? It is not Dropbox, Dropbox icon is fine.

Comment: Did you try right click, indicator settings and see what gives?

Comment: What do you mean?  I know it is Application indicator and there is no info in right click menu. I can disable all Application indicators, but that's about it.

Comment: Right click in the Ubuntu indicator plugin area.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? I am talking about indicator-plugin and its Application indicators. There is no information about Application indicators other than to enable/disable them.

Comment: So this broken indicator doesn't appear listed there?

Comment: The broken icon is for some Application indicator. It is part of Application indicators. I can only enable/disable Application indicators completely. Your question does not make any sense. Or you maybe don't know what Application indicators are.

Comment: I can only guess this is not a Xubuntu clean install (unity leftovers?) Or you modified something in the panel.

Comment: It is xubuntu-desktop install over standard Ubuntu. It does not seem as unity leftover, it appeared after upgrade to 16.10.

Comment: I need to know how to debug this issue.

Comment: You could open your panel settings and set one of the default panel styles... If it doesn't bother you to customize your panel again. P.D. you can also save your current configuration.

Comment: The Application indicators are generated by libapplication.so library. That much I already found out.

Comment: I already tried resetting styles, removing the panel completely, etc. Also tried to create new user and he was affected too. So it is a problem with some system wide configuration.

Comment: This is the list of the installed packages related to indicator I have in a Xubuntu clean install, maybe it helps: gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1   
indicator-application    
indicator-messages    
indicator-sound     
libappindicator1    
libappindicator3-1    
libindicator3-7     
xfce4-indicator-plugin

Comment: I have found someone with the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/765148/hide-org-kde-statusnotifieritem-appindicator